# Powershell Copy-Item recursively but don't include folder name

Tags: powershell

This is a stupid question, but I just don't know why it isn't working.

I am trying to copy the files from FolderA to FolderB recursively. I am doing this:

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\FolderA\" -Destination "C:\FolderB\" -recurse -Force -Verbose
```

It works great, no problem.

Except the result in FolderB is this:

```
C:\FolderB\FolderA\file.txt
```

Whereas I want it to be:

```
C:\FolderB\file.txt
```

What stupid obvious thing am I missing?

Comment: You  are doing nothing stupid, copy-item is just a PITA.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your command is telling PowerShell to copy the folder itself, with all its contents, to the destination folder. To copy only the contents of the original folder, change your path as follows:

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\FolderA\*" -Destination "C:\FolderB\" -recurse -Force -Verbose
```

Notice the asterisk (*) after the folder name. This will copy the content (including subfolders) of the folder, but not the folder itself to the destination folder.

[Using the Copy-Item Cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156818.aspx)

Comment: Note that this *doesn't* copy the folder structure if destination folder does not exist. Calling `md "C:\FolderB"` before `Copy-Item` seems to avoid this problem.

Comment: Building on @zett42's comment above, if the destination folder does not already exist, it seems `Copy-Item` will reproduce the folder structure, but one level down (e.g. `C:\FolderA\B\C` is copied to `C:\FolderB\C` instead of `C:\FolderB\B\C`), and may also fail when multiple subfolders exist. Always ensure the destination folder exists before calling Copy-Item. This smells like a bug (I can't see any reason why this inconsistent behaviour would be desirable).

Comment: See also [comment on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5926430/1836776).

Comment: I had *.* and it still didn't copy the subfolders.  Changing to just * fixed this issue.

Comment: This approach does not work: it errors out with `Container cannot be copied onto existing leaf item.` for every single subdirectory you want to copy.

Comment: Okay - it turns out you *have to* ensure the target top-level root directory exists. You don't have to use `md`, you can also use `New-Item`. If you don't, then the top-level root directory still gets created, and some directories and some files may get copied over - but not *all* of them. This behavior can only be described as a horrendous Powershell bug that has not been fixed in Powershell 7+ and still exists in 2024.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-File -Recurse` for Copy only Files Recursively:

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Source" -Destination "C:\Dest" -File -recurse -Force -Verbose
```

Or use `-Directory -Recurse` to copy only empy folder structure:

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Source" -Destination "C:\Dest" -Directory -recurse -Force -Verbose
```

Comment: -File seems to not be a valid parameter any more.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `-Container:$false` will omit the directory structure:

```
Copy-Item -Path C:\temp\tree -Filter *.txt -Recurse -Container:$false
```

Docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.1#example-12--recursively-copy-files-from-a-folder-tree-into-the-current-folder

Comment: If you using this for a folder it also skips hidden folders